# Android onfocuschange in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, focus

I have an Android app, and in the xml layout file I have something like this:

```
    <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxDone"
    android:checked="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="doneCheckBoxClicked" />
```

Then in the java code I implemented

```
    public void doneCheckBoxClicked(View v) { ...}
```

Can I use similar approach for focus changing actions. Have in the xml something like

```
android:onFocusChanged="editTextFieldFocusChanged"
```

and then in java code:

```
public void editTextFieldFocusChanged(View v, boolean hasFocus) { ...}
```

Or there is no way to do onFocusChange in the xml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't set focus change listener of editext in xml file like onclick listener. We need to do it in Java file only.

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Android data binding to bind your handlers then you could write a custom BindingAdapter anywhere in your code to pass your handler from xml to java:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:onFocusChange")
public static void onFocusChange(EditText text, final View.OnFocusChangeListener listener) {
    text.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
}
```

And in Handler.java write a getter that returns an anonymous class:

```
public class Handler {
    public View.OnFocusChangeListener getOnFocusChangeListener() {
        return new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean isFocussed) {
                System.out.print("S");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now in your xml you can pass in the handler like this:

```
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="handler" type="Handler" />
    </data>
    <EditText app:onFocusChange="@{handler.OnFocusChangeListener}"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: this surely works! every time focus is changed `System.out.print("S");` is excuted since we've attached focus change listener

Comment: Including the `app:` prefix in the `@BindingAdapter` declaration will generate a compiler warning. Binding adapters expect their bound attributes to be in the `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` namespace, so even though `app:` is the prefix usually bound to that namespace, it's misleading to include it because it implies that you had the choice to use a different namespace instead. Just annotate the method with `@BindingAdapter("onFocusChange")` . In the XML, of course, you still need the `app:` prefix on the attribute name as usual.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property in XML like onFocusChanged.You have to handle the focus change in java code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally it's not used in xml declaration, you could add the `android:focusable` XML attribute to the View, in your layout declaration end set it true. Then you have to handle the focus change in your java code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `android` XML namespace equivalent for an `OnFocusChangeListener` as you describe, but theoretically you could implement something similar using Reflection and the Android Data Binding Library, although I would probably avoid that - It is much cleaner to just handle the focus change in Java.