# Change TextSize of focussed EditText in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Can any of you show me the best way to change the TextSize attribute of an EditText just when the user has it selected (is writing)?

This is what i accomplished so far:

I've two EditText in a linear layout.

xml:

```
<EditText
   android:textSize="20dp"
   android:onClick="makeTextViewFocusedBigger"/>
<EditText
   android:textSize="20dp"
   android:onClick="makeTextViewFocusedBigger"/>
```

activity:

```
public void makeTextViewFocusedBigger(View view) {
   ((EditText) view).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25);
}
```

When the user select it it does become bigger, but obviously it does not go back to the original size when the user stop using it.

What would you do to realize this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `View.OnFocusChangedListener`

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
       // Change size based on hasFocus boolean
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to set the method to be called on focus change via xml?

Answer (score 2):

Use `setOnFocusChangeListener`

Like This :

```
Your_Edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus)
                {
                    Your_Edittext.setTextSize(25); //increased size
                }
                else
                {
                    Your_Edittext.setTextSize(15); //normal size
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is there any way to set the method to be called on focus change via xml?

Comment: @D.Rek I think no

Answer (score 2):

Do following :

XML:

```
  <EditText
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/edit_text_first"/>
    <EditText
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/edit_text_second"/>
```

Activity `OnCreate`:

```
 EditText editFirst=findViewById(R.id.edit_first)

 EditText editSecond=findViewById(R.id.edit_second)

editFirst.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
       // Change size of text inside 1st EditText
    }
});

editSecond.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
       // Change size of text inside 2nd EditText
    }
});
```

To implement it more general :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnFocusChangeListener{ 


    @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            editFirst.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

            editSecond.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
        {
            // Change text size of every EditText or for selective EditText. As You want
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement View.OnFocusChangeListener(). This method is called when the focus state of a view has changed.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus)
        {
           // Change size when editText has focus
           editText.setTextSize(30);
        }else
        {
             // Change size when editText doesn't has focus
             editText.setTextSize(15);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `addFocusChangedListener` to your `EditTexts`. In them you can see if they are focused or not.

Comment: Is there any way to set the method to be called on focus change via xml?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement`View.OnFocusChangeListener()` method , set the textview size according you want in `onFocusChange()`

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
      // set the text size here
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to set the method to be called on focus change via xml?

Comment: sorry it cant be possible, have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37788549/5110595)